# How to post on Facebook business page using graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Posting on Business page using graph API is working but is always shows in notifications, and not on timeline.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the access token that you are using. If you are posting using a user access token, it should appear as a post to the page on the LHS of the page as a Visitor Post. If you are an admin of the page, then you can use the [page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens) to post as the page on the page's timeline.